# Azure B2C Custom Policy Introduce New claim

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

My team is very new to Azure B2C and we are trying to work through figuring out how we can further customize custom policies.  In this instance we have create a custom password change policy using this walkthrough:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-password-change-custom.  As an experiment I want to alter the user journey to only execute a step, in this case the step to actually change the password, if a certain claim exists.  I arbitrarily chose the "state" property as the claim I want to check.  I understand how to add a "PreCondition" to the user journey steps to check if a claim exists, what I can't figure out is how to make the "state" claim exist at that point.  I hope I am explaining in a way that makes sense, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is very deepl technical content and SO is not the place to ask how to solve it, before you even tried it.

Since you already got yourself familiar with the general complexity of custom policies, you may want to check this [source here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-advanced-policies/tree/master/Documentation). It contains a lot of complex scenarios - all implemented in the public demo site https://aka.ms/aadb2cdemo

Answer (score 0):

You can create a string claim: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/string-transformations#createstringclaim

Or you can check if the claim exists: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/general-transformations#doesclaimexist

Once you have a boolean value, you can add it into your precondition.